# How to add columns to ledgertrans

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

I have to add a new column in ledgerTrans, and write data, but I don't want to do that with a direct x++ insert. I preffer do it throught a class and rights methods.

I've saw classes like LedgerJournalCheckPost and CustVendVoucher but I've gotten good results.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add an accessor to the LedgerVoucherTransObject to set that field
2. If your field needs to be grouped for summarized transaction add it to list of fields in LedgerVoucher.initLedgerTransList
3. Set accessor added in step 1 when LedgerVoucherTransObject is created.

Add breakpoint to LedgerVoucherObject.addTrans and walk up through call stack to find the proper place for 3.